# Sending an ArrayList of serialized objects to client (TCP) from server

Tags: java, serialization, tcp, arraylist

My first question is that should I serialize each individual object in the arrayList or should I serialize the whole arrayList because I know that ArrayLists are serializable.

Also, how would I send it from a server to a client. I'm thinking of using ObjectOutputStream on the server side. But I think my instructor wants each and every object to be serialized.

How would I serialize each object and then add it to the ArrayList. After adding it to the ArrayList, I'd need to send the ArrayList to client which after receiving it, will de-serialize each object and read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How would I serialize each object and then add it to the ArrayList.

You wouldn't. You would just add it to the `ArrayList` and serialize that.

> After adding it to the ArrayList, I'd need to send the ArrayList to client which after receiving it, will de-serialize each object and read it.

No. The client will deserialize the `ArrayList`. Done.

Comment: You think you could maybe give me a clue on how to send a serialized ArrayList over TCP like what type of stream or should I should something else?

Comment: @AnAlien Eh? You've already mentioned `ObjectOutputStream` yourself. That's the answer.

Comment: Oh okay. So just add the objects to an arrayList like normal and then use the objectOutputStream to send the ArrayList, right?

Answer (score 0):

No matter how you achieve serializing the items, you'll also need to serialize whatever you send them in.  I see no real difference between serializing a list of serializables vs. doing so individually.  Then you'd still have to serialize the list itself.

If you are not required to use ObjectInputStream, just to serialize and send, consider using XML.  You have a couple options - [XMLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/XMLEncoder.html)/[XMLDecoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/XMLDecoder.html) (older) or [JAXB](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/) (newer), for example.  One advantage with XML serialization over ObjectInput/OutputStream is the data is textual and (relatively) human readable on-the-wire.

Comment: Thanks, but I think I need to stick with ObjectInputStream. I don't know if my teacher for recognize XML serialization and approve of it.

Comment: "You'll also need to serialize whatever you send them in". No you won't. You *only* need to serialize the container.

Comment: The OP specifically asked if he could just serialize contents. While I agree with you that all you need is to serialize the collection, the OP was contemplating item by item serialization. My point was that regardless of your efficiency - all at once or one by one, the fact remains the collection itself must be serialized to send outside the jvm.